# Clean way of distinct values from objects array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have such model class:

```
struct AnswerModel:Decodable {
        let questionId,answerId:Int?
        var answer:Int?
        
        enum CodingKeys: String,CodingKey {
            case answer
            
            case questionId = "question"
            case answerId = "answer_id"
        }
        
    }
```

and sometimes array of this objects can contain elements with similar `questionId`. I did distinction in such way:

```
self.userAnswers += (pollsJson?.userAnswers)!
                
                
var seen = Set<Int>()
var unique = [PollsArray.AnswerModel]()
for element in self.userAnswers{
    if !seen.contains(element.questionId!) {
       unique.append(element)
       seen.insert(element.questionId!)
    }
}
                
self.userAnswers = unique
```

so as a result I receive array with unique values. Maybe someone will suggest smth better?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `AnswerModel` conform to `Hashable`, define your custom equality to only check `questionId` and then converting your `Array` to a `Set` will remove duplicates automatically.

```
extension AnswerModel: Hashable {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(questionId)
    }

    static func == (lhs: AnswerModel, rhs: AnswerModel) -> Bool {
        lhs.questionId == rhs.questionId
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
let userAnswers = [
    AnswerModel(questionId: 1, answerId: 1, answer: 1),
    AnswerModel(questionId: 1, answerId: 2, answer: 3),
    AnswerModel(questionId: 2, answerId: 1, answer: 1)
    ]

let unique = Set(userAnswers) // {questionId 1, answerId 1, answer 1} and {questionId 2, answerId 1, answer 1}
```